# Calculate a total from autocomplete suggestion.data

Tags: html, jquery, autocomplete

I'm trying to write a small Jquery program with an autocomplete searchform. I would like the user to be able to add items from the autocomplete form to a sort of shopping list. I have difficulties finding a way to calculate and update the total price of all added products, I tried to store the prices, which are in suggestion.data and tot add it recusively to a total as in 
total = total + suggestion.data, but this seems not to be the way. Could someone help me to produce and display this total? My jQuery code is as follows:

```
var Price = {};
var Name = {};
var Totaal = {};

$(function () {
    var currencies = [
        {value:'TEXT-STRING',data:'5.50)'},
        {value:'TEXT-STRING2',data:'3.10)'},
    ];

    $('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
        lookup: currencies,
        onSelect: function (suggestion) {
            Price.fff = suggestion.data;
            Name.fff = suggestion.value;
        },   
    });
});

function addListItem() {
    var write2 = Price.fff;
    var write = $('#autocomplete').val();
    var list = $('#itemList');
    var item = $('<li><span class="list">' + write + '</span><button 
 class="delete">X</button></li>');

    var autocomplete = $("#autocomplete");

    if (write.length === 0 || write.length > 88) {
        return false;
    }

    if (write == Name.fff) {
        list.append(item);
        list2.append(item2);
        $(autocomplete).val('');
    }
    $(autocomplete).val('');

}

function deleteItem() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
}

$(function () {
    var add = $('#addItem');
    var autocomplete = $('#autocomplete');
    var list = $('#itemList');
    add.on('click', addListItem);
    list.on('click', '.delete', deleteItem);
    autocomplete.on('keypress', function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            addListItem();
        }
    }
```

And my HTML looks like:

```
  <body>
    <div id="box-1"> </div>
    <div id="box-2"> </div>
    <div id="page">
      <h1>Shop</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="main">
      <div id="top">
        <div id="form">
          <div id="searchfield">
            <input type="text" id="autocomplete" name="currency" class="biginput" placeholder="ADD ITEMS BELOW">
            <input type="submit" id="addItem" value="+">
          </div>
          <div class="line"> </div>
        </div>
        <div id="bottom">
          <div class="items">
            <ul id="itemList">
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep added item in array with prices, so you can recalculate total at any time. Don't forget to remove it from array when removing from the list.

Don't keep data in DOM, use DOM only to display info that is in your model.